# Case AndAlso combination

Tags: vb.net

Here is the code:

```
Select Case ConnectionId
  Case Is = 40113 AndAlso CompanyId= 88
```

Both are true, connectionId is 40113 and CompanyId is 88, yet the code goes to Case Else...

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set `OPTION STRICT` to ON. Then this would not even compile since you're trying to use an `Integer` as `Boolean`, that's also the reason for your issue. `40113`  will evaluate to `True` so `40113 AndAlso CompanyId= 88` will also evaluate to `True`, but `ConnectionId = True` will evaluate to `False`. ( you see why you should set `STRICT` )

Use an `If-Else` instead:

```
If ConnectionId = 40113 AndAlso CompanyId = 88 Then
    ' ... '
Else
    ' ... '
End If
```

In general:  if you want to compare multiple variables use an `If`- instead of a `Select Case`.

Comment: Some nitpicking: *40113 will evaluate to False with OPTION STRICT OFF*: that's not correct. It will evaluate to `True`, and hence `40113 AndAlso CompanyId= 88` will also evaluate to `True`, but `ConnectionId = True` will evaluate to `False`. Gotta love VB.Net with `Option Strict Off`!

Comment: @DominicKexel: Corrected, thanks. Yes, Option Strict Off is a mess, kind of _random-programming_, you never know what happens. I would never turn it off, even not for testing purposes like here ;)

Comment: `Option Strict Off` has it uses (Office interop), but it would be nice if you could use it at block level instead of only at file level.

Comment: Even at Office Interop it is often not neceassry. Simply turn of warnings for late bindings and set everything else to strict on settings. You have to do some casts more, but it is worth the trouble, especially in bigger interop apps.